# Bash split string into positional parameters

Tags: bash

I have a variable in bash let say,

`val="cmd arg1 arg2"`

I want to split into two parts such one part is command and other part will be all the arguments (i.e. `$0` & `$*`). How can I do this?

Sample cases it should work in:

> val="/c/Program\ Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vBoxManage.exe --help -ds"
>
> val="'/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vBoxManage.exe' --help -ds"
>
> val='"/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vBoxManage.exe" --help -ds'
>
> val="../run dsa"
>
> val="/fdfds/fds fds"

Comment: [Bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You shouldn't assume that all the whitespace in the string should be used for word-splitting.

Comment: @chepner Yes! I am taking quotes into count. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437173/bash-split-string-into-positional-parameters?noredirect=1#comment56616116_34437312. Also input of command is from bash history file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
while read -r val
do
    echo "The input val is:==$val=="
    declare -a 'arr=('"$val"')'
    cmd=${arr[0]}
    echo "Command is: ==$cmd=="
    unset arr[0]
    for arg in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        echo "  argument is: ==$arg=="
    done
    echo
done <<EOF
cmd arg1 arg2
cmd "arg1 1" "arg2 2"
"../so me/cmd md" arg1 arg2
"../so me/cmd md" arg1 "arg2 2"
EOF
```

it prints

```
The input val is:==cmd arg1 arg2==
Command is: ==cmd==
    argument is: ==arg1==
    argument is: ==arg2==

The input val is:==cmd "arg1 1" "arg2 2"==
Command is: ==cmd==
    argument is: ==arg1 1==
    argument is: ==arg2 2==

The input val is:=="../so me/cmd md" arg1 arg2==
Command is: ==../so me/cmd md==
    argument is: ==arg1==
    argument is: ==arg2==

The input val is:=="../so me/cmd md" arg1 "arg2 2"==
Command is: ==../so me/cmd md==
    argument is: ==arg1==
    argument is: ==arg2 2==
```

e.g.

```
val='"/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vBoxManage.exe" --help'
declare -a 'arr=('"$val"')'
cmd=${arr[0]}
unset arr[0]
args="${arr[@]}"
echo "cmd:==$cmd==  args:==$args=="
```

prints

```
cmd:==/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vBoxManage.exe==  args:==--help==
```